# Setting data properties on create to use in prop

Tags: vue.js

I have a component with a child component. In the parent, I get data in the created() hook. I set two data properties. In the parent, I then render the child and want to pass one of those two data properties conditionally.

So in my parent I have

```
  data () {
    return {
      isWorking: false,
      selectedTask: {},
      measurements: []
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      tasks: state => state.Task.taskRequestData
    }),
    finishedTasks () {
      return _.pickBy(this.tasks, function (el) {
        return el.finished
      })
    },
    unfinishedTasks () {
      return _.pickBy(this.tasks, function (el) {
        return !el.finished
      })
    }
  },
  ...
  created: function () {
    // Get the measurement currently running - if there is one.
    this.$store.dispatch(MEASUREMENT_REQUEST_CURRENT).then((res) => {
      // If there's a currently running measurement, set the state
      if (res.length !== 0) {
        this.selectedTask = res[0].task
        this.isWorking = true
      }
      // Else, do nothing.
    })
  }
```

and

```
<task-list
  :isWorking="isWorking"
  :selectedTaskIdProp="isWorking ? selectedTask.id : undefined"
  @startWork="startWork">
</task-list>
```

in my child, I have

```
  data () {
    return {
      selectedTaskId: this.selectedTaskIdProp
    }
  },
  props: {
    isWorking: Boolean,
    selectedTaskIdProp: {
      type: Number,
      default: undefined
    }
  }
```

Now, after everything is loaded, the selectedTask in the child is undefined instead of a number. It seems, as if the prop gets passed while isWorking is still false and once isWorking is updated, it doesn't retrigger the rendering.

How do I properly assign data properties before everything else? I looked at the [Lifecycle-Diagram](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram) of VueJS but I'm not sure when I can start setting data properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and all props are updating normally, however, the reason that `isWorking` is updating while `selectedTaskIdProp` does not, seem to be from the `id` attribute of `res[0].task` which does not have this attribute. Therefore, you should check if it has this attribute before passing it to the child, through something like:

```
:selectedTaskIdProp="(isWorking && selectedTask && selectedTask.id) ? selectedTask.id : undefined"
```

However, the main problem is in the response, so make sure to add the id to it in order to be passed to the child.

**EDIT AFTER DEBUGGING THE SANDBOX:**

You are setting `selectedTaskID` in the `data` of the child directly to the value of the passed `prop`, which won't work. The right way is to pass the value in `created()` of the child component as follows:

```
data() {
    return {
      selectedTaskIndex: undefined,
      selectedTaskID:null, //update this
      tasks: []
    };
},
```

```
created: function() {
    this.tasks = api.getTasks();
    console.log('set this.tasks in TasksLists.vue to')
    console.log(this.tasks);
    this.selectedTaskID = this.selectedTaskIDProp; //update this
}
```

Comment: `res[0].task` always has an `id`. I added `id: undefined` as an property of `selectedTask` so when passing the prop, I can just use `:selectedTaskIDProp="selectedTask.id"` but that doesn't work. I thought, maybe the reactivity system doesn't catch it because I never predefined the id - but now I did. hm

Comment: The problem is not in the reactivity, if the first prop is changing then the second will do as well. The way I tested it worked fine when setting the id. If you want more help, perhaps you can link a demo online for me to debug it.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-fast-e21u1?file=/src/components/TaskList.vue or just the app https://e21u1.csb.app/ I tried to reproduce it but I had to change quit a bit. If you load the code above, it gets the currently running task in created() of Timer.vue and set's it as a data proeprty. We then use that to pass it as a prop to TaskList.vue which renders all tasks. Now it should add the active class to the selected which doesn't happen since the prop never seems to "arrive".

Comment: I think my problem is actually handling the prop inTaskList.vue - it get's passed but selectedTaskID is still undefined. I'd like to set it to the prop value